# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined magento 2.3.2 in production mode

Tags: magento2, javascript, error, console, google-map

I am working with magento2.3.2.I am adding Google Maps to the template file. And it is adding successfully in the development environment but facing issues in the production server. I have attached a screenshot for reference. This is the error that I am facing in the console. I had also regenerated a js merged file but was still not able to solve this error.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: same issue there; did you manage to have any update on this ?

Comment: Yes, I resolved it. instead of directly adding the function use a callback parameter which will call a function in that function you can call add the google map keys etc